# getting error "ClassNotFoundException" in wicket

Tags: mysql, tomcat, deployment, wicket

i am making an application in Wicket that includes some database queries. This works fine when i try to run it from Tomcat on my local computer. However when try to upload it to the server or i do a mvn package on it, and then i try to run it on the server i get an error "ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

I do have a call out to the com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in my code:

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   String url1 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/smart_one";

However that works fine before deploying the project and running from Eclipse.

I have tried using glassFish on the server along with tomcat. I also tried doing a mvn package and deploying it on my localhost and it still give me the same error.

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<properties>
    <wicket.version>6.16.0</wicket.version>
    <jetty.version>7.6.13.v20130916</jetty.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <!-- allowed values: R7, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0 or none -->
    <wtp.version>none</wtp.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!--  WICKET DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    -->

    <!-- LOGGING DEPENDENCIES - LOG4J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  JUNIT DEPENDENCY FOR TESTING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--  JETTY DEPENDENCIES FOR TESTING  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-all-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-auth-roles</artifactId>
        <version>6.16.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: well... this is nearly imposible to answer without a) seeing the relevant parts of your pom b) more information on how you access your DB (like JPA or JDBC or....) c) more information on how you manage your db access (like JNDI or hardcoded urls or...)

Comment: Thanks for you looking into this for me. I realize that my jdbc driver was not included in the pom file and when i did that it started working.

Answer (score 0):

So i realized that when i deployed the project that i needed to add the jdbc driver in to my dependencies.

here is what i had to add to my pom.xml file under the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: When answering your own questions make sure others understand it's an answer and not a random comment.